# Fade in Animation not working in Android M

Tags: android, android-animation, android-6.0-marshmallow, fadein

I am developing in Android application in that I am using **fade-in** animation.

So it's working in below Android version (Kitkat, Lolipop, etc.) but when I tried to run in Android Marshmallow its not working.

I am using below code for fade-in animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Note: I am using Samsung Galaxy J7 device for test.

**Solution:**

After adding below line issue solved.

> android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: It works on **Android M**. How are you using it?

Comment: `Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);`
            `view.startAnimation(fadeIn);`

Comment: If I adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to Manifest.xml file its working but CardView not working after adding this line.

Comment: @SagarZala Are you using `RecyclerView` to load your items. If yes then you need to use `ItemAnimator`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html

Comment: No I am not using RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using Interpolator property of "set" tag. here is a good example of fade in and fade out animation.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, its working. After adding `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"` working fine.